# Dry up this httparty code and move it out of the controller and into the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, httparty

ArticlesController

```
def home
  @url =         'https://meta.discourse.org/latest.json'
  @forum_data =  HTTParty.get(@url).parsed_response
  @topic_one =   @forum_data['topic_list']['topics'][0]['title']
  @topic_two =   @forum_data['topic_list']['topics'][1]['title']
  @topic_three = @forum_data['topic_list']['topics'][2]['title']
  @topic_four =  @forum_data['topic_list']['topics'][3]['title']
  @topic_five =  @forum_data['topic_list']['topics'][4]['title']
end
```

articles/home.html.erb

```
<div class="topics">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <%= @topic_one %>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%= @topic_two %>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%= @topic_three %>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%= @topic_four %>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%= @topic_five %>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am struggling with how I can pass the integer into the object as a variable and I am also struggling with how I can create a method to move this into the model.

Comment: This is a better candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but I'll add an answer since it's relatively trivial.

Comment: You may want to use the presenter pattern to refactor this. Check this video as guide. https://youtu.be/OGdVJj-jNoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it in a PORO:

```
class ForumTopicList
  def initialize(discourse_forum_url)
    @forum_url = discourse_forum_url

    @forum_data =  HTTParty.get(@url).parsed_response
  end

  def topics
    @forum_data['topic_list']['topics'].map { |topic| ForumTopic.new(topic) }
  end

  class ForumTopic
    def initialize(topic_hash)
      @topic_hash = topic_hash
    end

    def title
      @topic_hash['title']
    end
  end
end
```

This will allow you to reduce your controller to:

```
def home
  url = 'https://meta.discourse.org/latest.json'

  @topics = ForumTopicList.new(url).topics.first(5)
end
```

And your view can become

```
<div class="topics">
  <ul>
    <%= @topics.each do |topic|>
      <li> <%= topic.title %> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I limit it to 5 topics?